# Why the sum of the list is 4？

Tags: summation, fourier-analysis

Wolfram Alpha says

```
Sum[Sin(Pi*n/4)]/(Pi*n/4),{n,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

is equal to *4*
but I don't know how to resolve it...

In my signal and system homework,this sequence is required to be identify what the type of this signal is,such as energy signal,power signal.
So I encounter this problem.

Even though the n=0 is not defined,the W|A also says

```
Sum[Sin(Pi*n/4)]/(Pi*n/4),{n,1,Infinity}]
```

is 1.4999999999...(The symbolic exptession is very complex,it can not simplify to 1.5).

Or,Can  we prove the summation have **boundry**?

Howerver,Using the Fourier transform,the `Integrate[Sin(x)/x,{n,-Infinity,Infinity}]`  can be resolve.But if it is a sequence,How to solve it?

Comment: Is that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\frac{\pi n}{4}}{\frac{\pi n}{4}}$$?

Comment: Could you explain what that Wolfram input means in ordinary mathematical notation? It seems to have two `]` but only one `[`, which looks strange.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That also Ok.

Comment: Is it really from $-\infty$ to $\infty$? It isn't defined at $n=0$. @user15961

Comment: @AlexSilva: Not if Thomas Andrews' interpretation is true. The terms for $n=8k+1,8k+2,8k+3$ are positive and absolutely larger than the negative terms for $n=8k+5,8k+6,8k+7$, and this pattern continues towards infinity.

Comment: What is your definition for $n=0$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Perhaps it is $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \operatorname{sinc}(\frac\pi4n)$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm RIght!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Even though the n==0 isn't be difined, the function get the sum 1.5 when n from 1 to Infinity

Comment: @HenningMakholm Does look better now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(need to fix the end. This is the right idea, but the end conclusion appears wrong.)

$$-\log(1-z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$$

when $|z|\leq 1$ and $z\neq 1$.

Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin nx}{nx}$ is the imaginary part of:

$$\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{inx}}{n}=-\frac{\log(1-e^{ix})}{x}$$

When $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$, this is the imaginary part of:

$$-\frac{\log\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)}{\frac{\pi}{4}}$$ The imaginary part of this is $$\frac{\arctan(\sqrt 2+1)}{\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

and $\arctan(\sqrt 2+1)=\frac{3\pi}{8}$.

To see that last, take the triangle $A=0,B=1,C=1-e^{ix}$. Since $|AB|=|BC|=1$, you have an isosceles triangle. The imaginary part of $-\log\left(1-e^{ix}\right)$ is just the angle $\angle A$. $\angle B=x=\frac{\pi}{4}$, and so $\angle A=\angle C$ gives $\angle C=\frac{3\pi}{8}$.

Comment: How to think so far? How to think about the first equation?

Comment: What do you mean "How to think about?" It is a well-known expression. It is proved by differentiating and seeing you get $\frac{1}{1-z}$, but that doesn't explain why it converges when $|z|=1$ and $z\neq 1$, which is more complicated.

Comment: I don't really familiar with A,B,C are they coordinates or vectors or points.Points have values? I have never seen before... It is so strange

Comment: They are the points of a triangle in the complex plane. @user15961 I was just giving a reason for why $\arctan(1+\sqrt{2})=\frac{3\pi}{8}$.

Comment: A point have value 1?     I don't understand.

Comment: $1=1+0i$ corresponds to $(x,y)=(1,0)$. That's the way the complex plane works. @user15961

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't have time to teach you how the complex plane works. I assumed if you understood the beginning of my answer, you knew a few things about the complex numbers. $1-e^{ix}=1-\cos(x) -i\sin x$ corresponds to $(x,y)=(1-\cos x,-\sin x)$. 
I'm not sure you meant it, but saying  "X is not straightforward" is an insulting way of saying, "I don't understand X," because it implies that the person who wrote the answer was inarticulate.